# How to display input value in custom component dynamically after pressing button in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display 'custom-form' input element data to child component 'status-bar' after pressing button 'Send', but when the button is pressed, simply nothing happens. Any ideas why? Please see link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/L15fupya/

```
productForm.component('status-bar', {
    props: ['outputData'],
    template: '<p v-html="outputData"></p>',
    data(){
        return {
            outputData: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething (data) {
            this.outputData = data
            console.log(this.outputData)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below changes for both `template` as well `js`. You will be able to understand the flow when you compare the below with your `JSFiddle` code

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <div id="product_form">
        <h1>Product Add</h1>
        <div class="lines">
            <custom-form></custom-form>
           // Change added (Moved send button inside custom-form component
        </div>
    </div>
```

and `js` code is

```
      var productForm = Vue.createApp ({})
        
        productForm.component('custom-form', {  
            components: ['status-bar'],
            template: `
                <label>Name<input type="text" v-model="this.product.name" @change="doSomething(this.product.name)"></label> <button v-on:click="submitProduct">Send</button><button v-on:click="closeStatus">Hide</button>
                <status-bar v-show="statusVisible" :outputData="outputData">{{outputData}}</status-bar>
                ` , // Change added
            
            data: function() {
                return {
                    product: {
                        name: 'asdf'
                    },
                    outputData: '<div>Sample</div>', // Change added
                    statusVisible: false // Change added
                }
            },

           // Methods section added
           methods: {
            submitProduct() {
              this.statusVisible = true;
            },
            closeStatus() {
              this.statusVisible = false;
            }
           }
        })
        
        productForm.component('status-bar', {
            props: ['outputData'],
            template: '<p v-html="outputData"></p>',
            data(){
                return {
                    outData: '' // Change added
                }
            },
            methods: {
                doSomething (data) {
                    this.outData = data
                    console.log(this.outputData)
                }
            }
        })
        
        const vm = productForm.mount('#product_form')
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works for me :)

Comment: @v01d Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would upvote the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have.

Comment: Based on your instructions I rearranged my code and now data flows flawlessly :))

Comment: Nice man...glad that iam able to help